# RStudio wrongfully shows bracket warnings

Tags: r, rstudio

I checked my function on ideone.com (https://ideone.com/Z2pVQp
) because RStudio wrongfully shows unmatched braket warning signs next to line 1, 29, 34, 87 only after you saved the file.

Since the function is quite large I spare to post it all in the question section but will give you for example the lines 29 - 34 which might be the hook to this problem.

```
   missinggames <-  map_df(1:nrow(missinggames), ~if(missinggames$Goals_team_home[.x] > missinggames$Goals_team_away[.x])
      mutate(missinggames[.x,], points_team_home =  3, points_team_away = 0) else if
      (missinggames$Goals_team_home[.x] == missinggames$Goals_team_away[.x])
        mutate(missinggames[.x,], points_team_home =  1, points_team_away = 1) else
          mutate(missinggames[.x,], points_team_home =  0, points_team_away = 3)
    )
```

Do I miss something here or how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you explain me why or help me to make it do what it should do?

Comment: Probably, I was wrong. It might work but can you try this alternative `missinggames %>%
  mutate(points_team_home = case_when(Goals_team_home > Goals_team_away ~3, 
                                      Goals_team_home == Goals_team_away ~ 1, 
                                      TRUE ~ 0), 
         points_team_away = case_when(Goals_team_home > Goals_team_away ~0, 
                                      Goals_team_home == Goals_team_away ~ 1, 
                                      TRUE ~ 3)) ` ?

Comment: Very good. I looked for that answear in my brain but couldn't come up with it. This also fixed the braket problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `case_when` here :

```
library(dplyr)

missinggames %>%
  mutate(points_team_home = case_when(Goals_team_home > Goals_team_away ~3, 
                                      Goals_team_home == Goals_team_away ~ 1, 
                                      TRUE ~ 0), 
         points_team_away = case_when(Goals_team_home > Goals_team_away ~0, 
                                      Goals_team_home == Goals_team_away ~ 1, 
                                      TRUE ~ 3))
```